# How to perform jpeg encoding of a BIG RGB-image in parallel?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, jpeg, image-compression

I have to compress a very big image using jpeg (image size `> 100 MB` ).

I'm now encoding using openCV 3.4.3 (openCV uses libjpeg-turbo 1.5) and it takes me `750 [ms]` for a `129 MB` RGB-image ( `7250 * 621 * 3` ), but it uses a single thread.

I would like to **speed up the jpeg encoding (and decoding) by using threads**.

**How to do it?**

I'm using a Windows machine,

I can use IPP (Intel's) if it helps.

Comment: You might try `libvips` https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/using-from-cpp.html Or maybe you could thread your application across a different dimension, i.e. rather than process one image at a time by multiple threads each processing a different part of the same image, instead process multiple images at a time each by a single thread.

Comment: What is your throughput target for doing so ( a baseline performance cadence - in pictures per second )?

Comment: @user3666197, 
I have just one big image.
The target is to finish the task with shortest latency as possible.
My user is waiting to much to his output

Comment: Some *ImageMagick* routines are multi-threaded but I don't know if converting to JPEG is.  Might be worth finding out.

Comment: Depending on the content of your file it could make quite a large file on disk - say 70MB - so if your PC has conventional spinning disks that can only do 150MB/s you could have 500ms of I/O. Maybe try writing on a RAMdisk - like the one by DataRam to see if that helps.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, The raw image is caclulated and  kept on RAM memory and the encoded size is 1 to 5 MB depends on the image and also kept  (at least it the beginning on the RAM)

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"How to perform jpeg encoding of a BIG RGB-image in parallel?"*
>   
> <sub>*@user3666197, I have just one big image. The target is to finish the task with shortest latency as possible. My user is waiting to much to his output – Ido 5 hours ago*</sub>

The JPEG encoding, produced from an RGB-array, can be [performed](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~web6140/TopTenAlgorithms/JPEG.html) in several principal steps:

1 ) **Color transform**: Convert RGB to YCbCr - easily parallelisable, no block / kernel-dependencies
2 ) JPEG **color / luminance downsampling** - easily parallelisable, no block / kernel-dependencies
3 ) **DCT on 8 x 8 blocks** - 2D discrete cosine transform - easily parallelisable on ( 8 x 8 )-blocks of data
4 ) **Zero removal & Huffman encoding** - AFAIK this, to work, has to be a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** stream-process

If interested in designing an efficient, ultimately low-latency processing, the best results will require not going to re-use a COTS / universal code, but going deeper, into rewriting the top-down processing, best following the cache-line re-use patterns and doing as much as possible using CPU-native vectorised instructions ( be it using an inlined assembly code or AVX / AVX2 / AVX512 intrinsics )